# R markdown pdf document

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pdfdocument

how do I separate headings (in r markdown pdf document) with the text? After knitting I get an output such as:

**Linear Regression**   linear regression is a

Instead of

**linear regression**

Linear regression is a..

I'm using the '#' way of formatting headings

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include the markdow  code that you are using with your question.

Comment: try to add an additional linebreak.